# detecting user events in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following code in which I try to react to user events in pygame:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.time import set_timer
from sys import exit

def timerFunc():
    print "Timer CallBack"

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0,32)
set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 1000)

while True:
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed_keys[K_SPACE]:
        exit()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print event
        if event == QUIT:
            exit()
        if event == USEREVENT+1:
            timerFunc()
```

Unfortunately the `timerFunc()` doesn't get executed, events are propagated by the `set_timer()` function, since in the output I get:

```
<Event(25-UserEvent {'code': 0})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `event.type` attribute:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print event
    if event.type == QUIT:
        exit()
    if event.type == USEREVENT+1:
        timerFunc()
```